# File handling between akka and play

Tags: scala, file, playframework, akka

I want to send a file from controller to an actor who receives the file and extracts metadata.

```
import app.model.Bill
import com.google.common.io.Files
import play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile
import play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData
import play.core.parsers.Multipart.FilePartHandler

//model
case class UploadFile(billFile: MultipartFormData.Part[Files.TemporaryFile])

//Controller
val fileUploadActor = ActorSystem().actorOf(Props[FileUploaderActor])

def uploadBillFile = Action(parse.multipartFormData){ implicit  request =>
    request.body.file("billFile").map {billFile => 
    val stats = fileUploadActor ! UploadFile(billFile)
 }

// Actor
class FileUploaderActor extends Actor{
  override def receive: Receive = {

    case UploadFile(billFile : FilePartHandler[TemporaryFile]):
      val filename = billFile.filename
      println("filename :" + filename)
    /* implementation goes like this */
  }
}
```

My problem is the type "MultipartFormData.Part[Files.TemporaryFile]" is not resolving in the case class "UploadFile" to pass a file to an actor.

Please suggest a solution to solve this, thanks in advance.

Comment: I would really suspect this is not a good idea to separate this logic into the actor, are you sure you really need this? What is the purpose of this logic separation??

Comment: Yes, i want this file upload to be async and non blocking.

Comment: well, so maybe this need to be done in async controller method?

Comment: I want this to be scalable too. I am not sure about the async controller since i am new to play. Cant it be done through akka actors?

Comment: Please read documentation, next link could be good place to start: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAsync

Comment: @Pavel I think this is not the one i want. I need to play the file with multiple services by driving through messages. Like "upload a file" , "Standardie" and "store" whenever the message receives. Thats why i want to use akka actors here.

Comment: Did you try samples from LightBend website ? http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/simple-akka-http-multipart-formdata

Comment: On which line are you having issue? the codes seems to be working. Can you provide your stacktrace?

Comment: @RaKa In the case class, says "cannot resolve TemporaryFile"

Comment: I think Temporary file is not in scope. have you imported play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile ?

Comment: Yeah i did. I have updated my question with all my imports

Comment: It works now! 
Added like "case class UploadFile(billFile: MultipartFormData.FilePart[TemporaryFile])" .

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by replacing the "Part" with "FilePart" in the type definition.

```
case class UploadFile(billFile: MultipartFormData.FilePart[Files.TemporaryFile])
```

It worked after i have updated like above mentioned.

Thanks guys who helped me to identify the issue.